# linq check if a value exists in a list

Tags: linq, group-by

I am trying to group by my table with multiple columns and checking if the grouping count is equal to 2. I have the query working for this part

```
var query = from product in Products
            group by new { product.Product, product.Location, product.Customer } into grp
            where grp.Count() != 2
```

The Product has an another property Category, which could only have two values "High" & "Low".
How can I change this query to handle the check for Category in addition to the grouping count.

```
Product    Location   Customer    Category
  A           X         C1          High
  A           X         C1          Low
  A           Y         C1          High
  A           Y         C1          Low
  A           Y         C1          Low
  B           X         C1          High
  B           X         C1          Medium
```

In the example above, except for Product A at Location X and Customer C1, all other records are invalid. The Location Y has two Lows and Product B has a category Medium which is not part of the list: High & Low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include only specific categories, use a `where ..` expression:

```
var query = from product in Products
            where product.Category == "Low" || product.Category == "High"
            group ...
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I want to identify the records whose category is not Low or High and if they are Low & High, then I need to ensure there is only one Low & one High record. I can see how I could get in done two different queries but was hoping I could use a single query to achieve this.